# Is UFW working? Still seeing many sshd entries to log file

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, firewall, elementary-os

I recently enabled the firewall on my Elementary OS system, using `ufw`.

Here is my `sudo ufw status verbose`:

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip
```

Then I only allow ports for ssh (22), printing (cups port), and my media server.

The problem is I am still seeing many sshd log entries in journalctl such as this:

```
Aug 30 12:07:08 elementaryos sshd[8225]: Invalid user yale from 125.43.68.83 port 63475
Aug 30 12:07:08 elementaryos sshd[8225]: Received disconnect from 125.43.68.83 port 63475:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Aug 30 12:07:08 elementaryos sshd[8225]: Disconnected from invalid user yale 125.43.68.83 port 63475 [preauth]
Aug 30 12:11:31 elementaryos sshd[8327]: Invalid user rx from 49.234.116.13 port 53310
Aug 30 12:11:31 elementaryos sshd[8327]: Received disconnect from 49.234.116.13 port 53310:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Aug 30 12:11:31 elementaryos sshd[8327]: Disconnected from invalid user rx 49.234.116.13 port 53310 [preauth]
Aug 30 12:24:42 elementaryos sshd[8627]: Invalid user sftp_user from 142.44.211.229 port 39952
Aug 30 12:24:43 elementaryos sshd[8627]: Received disconnect from 142.44.211.229 port 39952:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Aug 30 12:24:43 elementaryos sshd[8627]: Disconnected from invalid user sftp_user 142.44.211.229 port 39952 [preauth]
Aug 30 12:31:56 elementaryos sshd[8789]: Invalid user chris from 128.199.154.237 port 42658
Aug 30 12:31:56 elementaryos sshd[8789]: Received disconnect from 128.199.154.237 port 42658:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Aug 30 12:31:56 elementaryos sshd[8789]: Disconnected from invalid user chris 128.199.154.237 port 42658 [preauth]
Aug 30 12:40:44 elementaryos sshd[9270]: Invalid user admin from 139.59.14.210 port 51780
Aug 30 12:40:45 elementaryos sshd[9270]: Connection closed by invalid user admin 139.59.14.210 port 51780 [preauth]
Aug 30 12:43:31 elementaryos sshd[9630]: Invalid user test from 139.59.14.210 port 43548
Aug 30 12:43:31 elementaryos sshd[9630]: Connection closed by invalid user test 139.59.14.210 port 43548 [preauth]
Aug 30 12:46:10 elementaryos sshd[9690]: Connection closed by authenticating user root 139.59.14.210 port 35310 [preauth]
Aug 30 12:55:33 elementaryos sshd[11834]: Received disconnect from 186.225.255.116 port 20373:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Aug 30 12:55:33 elementaryos sshd[11834]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 186.225.255.116 port 20373 [preauth]
```

These requests should be blocked by my firewall. What is the explanation for all these sshd log entries?

Comment: (1) "I allow ports for ssh..."  (2) "These requests should be blocked by my firewall."   These two statements are contradictory.  If you allow ssh connections, then you can expect to see (failed) ssh connections in your system logging.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have edited my question now. I only allow port 22 for ssh. All the log entries are from random high numbered ports, which should be blocked.

Comment: You are probably not blocking _any_ source ports.  You are blocking _destination_ ports other than 22, 443, 631... but all those ssh connections are coming _from_ some high-numbered port _to_ port 22 on your machine.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Note that _all_ ssh connections (in normal usage) are from random high-numbered ports.  Connect to this machine via `ssh` (a connection which you, as an authorized user, would want the firewall to allow), and issue `echo $SSH_CONNECTION`.  You will see the source IP, source port, destination IP, and destination port for the connection.

Comment: @user4556274 Thanks for the explanation. Makes total sense now. I was surprised by how many ssh attempts I get on my home network.